# rpc.gssd - krb5.conf with includedir

Tags: kerberos, nfs, mit-kerberos

I am trying to create a nfs kerberos configuration with `includedir`. The context is the following :

- default realm points to TEST.REALM.COM (hadoop installation)
- nas/nfs realm points to NFS.ANOTHER.REALM.COM

When I put all `realms` and `domain realms` in the `krb5.conf` file, I am able to mount my nfs share. When I use the `includedir` tag, thinks won't work out.

Here is my `krb5.conf`

```
includedir /etc/krb5.conf.d/

[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 dns_lookup_kdc = false
 forwardable = true
 allow_weak_crypto = false
```

Here is the config file for the default hadoop realm

```
[libdefaults]
 default_realm = TEST.REALM.COM

 TEST.REALM.COM = {
  ticket_lifetime = 1d
  renew_lifetime = 14d
 }

[realms]
 TEST.REALM.COM = {
  kdc = admhadoop1.realm.com
  kdc = admhadoop1.realm.com
  admin_server = admhadoop1.realm.com
 }

[domain_realm]
 .realm.com = TEST.REALM.COM
 realm.com = TEST.REALM.COM
```

Here is the config for the nfs realm

```
[libdefaults]
 NFS.ANOTHER.REALM.COM = {
  ticket_lifetime = 14d
  renew_lifetime = 180d
 }

[realms]
 NFS.ANOTHER.REALM.COM = {
  kdc = admnfs1.realm.com
  kdc = admnfs2.realm.com
  admin_server = admnfs1.realm.com
 }

[domain_realm]
 nfs01.realm.com = NFS.ANOTHER.REALM.COM
```

The `/etc/krb5.keytab` only containes the users host, nfs and root for the test01 server

Whit this configuration when I try to mount a share from `nfs01.realm.com` I'll get this kind of error :

```
rpc.gssd[7078]: dir_notify_handler: sig 37 si 0x7fff55a1d130 data 0x7fff55a1d000
rpc.gssd[7078]: dir_notify_handler: sig 37 si 0x7fff55a185b0 data 0x7fff55a18480
rpc.gssd[7078]: dir_notify_handler: sig 37 si 0x7fff55a1d130 data 0x7fff55a1d000
rpc.gssd[7078]: handling gssd upcall (/var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs/nfs/clnt16)
rpc.gssd[7078]: handle_gssd_upcall: 'mech=krb5 uid=0 enctypes=18,17,16,23,3,1,2 '
rpc.gssd[7078]: handling krb5 upcall (/var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs/nfs/clnt16)
rpc.gssd[7078]: process_krb5_upcall: service is '<null>'
rpc.gssd[7078]: Full hostname for 'nfs01.realm.com' is 'nfs01.realm.com'
rpc.gssd[7078]: Full hostname for 'test01.realm.com' is 'test01.realm.com'
rpc.gssd[7078]: No key table entry found for TEST01$@TEST.REALM.COM while getting keytab entry for 'TEST01$@TEST.REALM.COM'
rpc.gssd[7078]: No key table entry found for root/test01.realm.com@TEST.REALM.COM while getting keytab entry for 'root/test01.realm.com@TEST.REALM.COM
rpc.gssd[7078]: No key table entry found for nfs/test01.realm.com@TEST.REALM.COM while getting keytab entry for 'nfs/test01.realm.com@TEST.REALM.COM
rpc.gssd[7078]: No key table entry found for host/test01.realm.com@TEST.REALM.COM while getting keytab entry for 'host/test01.realm.com@TEST.REALM.COM
rpc.gssd[7078]: ERROR: gssd_refresh_krb5_machine_credential: no usable keytab entry found in keytab /etc/krb5.keytab for connection with host nfs01.realm.com
rpc.gssd[7078]: ERROR: No credentials found for connection to server nfs01.realm.com
rpc.gssd[7078]: doing error downcall
rpc.gssd[7078]: dir_notify_handler: sig 37 si 0x7fff55a1d130 data 0x7fff55a1d000
rpc.gssd[7078]: dir_notify_handler: sig 37 si 0x7fff55a1d130 data 0x7fff55a1d000
rpc.gssd[7078]: destroying client /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs/nfs/clnt17
rpc.gssd[7078]: dir_notify_handler: sig 37 si 0x7fff55a1d130 data 0x7fff55a1d000
rpc.gssd[7078]: dir_notify_handler: sig 37 si 0x7fff55a1d130 data 0x7fff55a1d000
rpc.gssd[7078]: dir_notify_handler: sig 37 si 0x7fff55a1d130 data 0x7fff55a1d000
rpc.gssd[7078]: dir_notify_handler: sig 37 si 0x7fff55a1d130 data 0x7fff55a1d000
rpc.gssd[7078]: dir_notify_handler: sig 37 si 0x7fff55a1d130 data 0x7fff55a1d000
```

It looks like the nfs deamon doesn not work with the `includedir` tag.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that the files in the included directory should only have `alphanumerical` names (with "`-`" and "`_`") but no "`.`" like in my case.